# Derivative of Hadamard product with functions

Tags: matrices, derivatives, hadamard-product

I'm new to matrix derivatives, and I'm having a bit of trouble with this one in particular. I have this equation for the function:

$f(x) = M(g(x) ∘ g(x))$

Where M is a non-square matrix, '$∘$' is Hadamard product, and '$g(x)$' returns a matrix.

How would you go about deriving this?

Comment: what is x? a scalar or a vector or a matrix? and what do you want to differentiate with respect to?

Comment: And is the matrix $M$ multiplied by the matrix $(g(x) \circ g(x))$ or is $M$ a function returning a non-square matrix?

Comment: @mathreadler x is a vector, $M$ is being multiplied with $(g(x)∘g(x))$

Comment: Okay. So then $M(...)$ is a matrix and x is a vector. And what you want is to calculate all the partial derivatives wrt the elements of x of the elements of the matrix that f returns or something else? If that is the case you will need 3 indexes so you will need to choose some notation for it.

Comment: @mathreadler I don't want the exact partial derivatives, more the form the equation should take for it's derivatives. for example, I found some similar questions that have led me to think that $f'(x) = 2M^T(g'(x) ∘ g(x)) $, but that wasn't right. I just want to know how to determine the correct form.

Comment: The first problem is to decide what you actually want to calculate. There are very many senses you can define derivatives for multidimensional things. The second problem you need to address (if you want the partial derivatives wrt the elements in x) is to find a way to express it outside of linear algebra, because it will be something "larger" than a matrix, having 3 indexes instead of 2 which a matrix would.

Comment: @mathreadler I think if I gave bit more context about the problem you might be able to help.

Comment: @mathreadler I might have explained myself poorly. What you're describing is a bit above my current understanding. What I'm actually trying to find is $∇Af(x)$, the gradient of $A$ wrt $f(x)$. A is a matrix used inside $g(x)$. I know what the derivative of $∇Ag(x)$ is, I just can't figure out how it fits in. Does that help?

Comment: Yes maybe I could. But it is sometimes more important to learn to formulate for oneself "what do I actually want to achieve/calculate" or "how can I make this make sense". Yes that is good, learn to practice to formulate yourself better. Surprisingly often you may find you don't actually need to ask at all. (but it can still be good to do because you can get new ideas which you did not think of before.)

Comment: @mathreadler Yes I agree. I want to to be able to formulate this myself. See my comment other comment ^^. Does that help?

Comment: I think it can help if you think about what you want to calculate a bit more.

Comment: @mathreadler I want to find $∇Af(x)$ like I said in my previous comment? Or is that not what you meant?

Comment: You seem confused about what you want to calculate. It is very difficult to give advice if you don't know which question to ask.

Answer (score 2):

For consistency, I'll use uppercase letters for matrices 
and lowercase for vectors. I'll also use 
$$\eqalign{
&A\circ B \cr
&A:B = {\rm tr}(A^TB) \cr
&A\otimes B \cr
}$$
to denote the elementwise/Hadamard, trace/Frobenius, and 
Kronecker products, respectively.

Then the function of interest is 
$$F = M(G\circ G)$$
Use the vectorization and diagonalization operators to 
create some new variables
$$\eqalign{
f &= {\rm vec}(F)\cr
g &= {\rm vec}(G)\cr
\Gamma &= {\rm Diag}(g)\cr
A &= I\otimes M \cr
J &= \frac{\partial g}{\partial x} &\implies dg = J\,dx \cr
}$$
Now we are ready to find the differential and gradient of your function
$$\eqalign{
f &= {\rm vec}(M(G\circ G)I) = A\,(g\circ g) \cr
df&= 2A\,(g\circ dg) = 2A\Gamma J\,dx \cr
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} &= 2A\Gamma J \cr
\cr
\frac{\partial {\rm vec}(F)}{\partial x}
  &= 2\,(I\otimes M)\,\,{\rm Diag}\Big({\rm vec}(G)\Big)\,\,\frac{\partial {\rm vec}(G)}{\partial x} \cr
}$$